# Django Form Package Application to Bootstrap 3

Tags: python, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

How would you convert Django Form  from Package Application to Bootstrap 3. In my case I am working with  forms from [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth).

I would like Signup / Signin forms converted to Bootstrap3. I was hoping 
Django Crispy forms http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html
had the feature, have not been able to find it.

Comment: You cannot automatically convert them. You must override the templates of django-allauth with your own copies and modify them. Then you can use django-crispy-forms or django-bootstrap3.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with `django-allauth`, but you would probably not be able to find any out-of-the-box support for that in crispy forms. You should, however, be able to subclass each of its views and register URL patterns for the in your project, rather than including its `urls.py`. In case it uses function based views the overriding is going to be a bit more work though.

Essentially what you will want to do is add the necessary crispy form fields/wrappers etc. to the forms supplied by django-allauth in your own subclasses, and use these classes instead. I've successfully used that approach when dealing with django-shop, although I guess mileage will wary somewhat depending on if/how extensibility has been taken into account while designing django-allauth.

Also, as noted by Selcuk, depending on your needs overriding the template files might be sufficient, i.e. replacing `{{ form }}` with `{% crispy my_form %}`.

Comment: There is no need to subclass views; overriding the default templates with your own is sufficient.

Comment: Good point! I think you might very well want to subclass the views however, but it depends on what kind of bootstrap features you need. If all you want to do is use to crispy template tag - of course, no subclassing required. But if you need field grouping, input-append etc. subclassing is the way go IMO.